# Nlog Posting to a CosmosDB Target

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, nlog

I'm using Nlog and trying to make it post to a CosmosDB(DocumentDB) target 
using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nlog.DocumentDBTarget/

my configuration code looks like this

```
  var documentDBTarget = new DocumentDBTarget()
        {
            Name = "logDocument",
            EndPoint = "https://[my endpoint].documents.azure.com:443/",
            AuthorizationKey = "[my auth key]",
            Collection = "[my collection]",
            Database = "[my database]",
            Layout=jsonLayout
        }; 
        config.AddTarget(documentDBTarget);
        config.AddRuleForAllLevels(documentDBTarget);
```

I have declared jsonLayout and then I configure the logger and use it to start logging. this was working fine when I was logging to a local file target or a console target but it's not working with cosmosDB

```
LogManager.Configuration =config; 
Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Example");          
logger.Info("{object}");
```

what am I missing? the documentation for https://github.com/goto10hq/NLog.DocumentDB?files=1
I didn't find any information about posting using Nlog I only found info about configuring it which I believe I did correctly

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works on my computer. Is the object that you are trying to log consistent with the JSON layout?

```
var jsonLayout = new JsonLayout()
        {
            Attributes =
                {
                    new JsonAttribute("name", "${name}"),
                    new JsonAttribute("level", "${level}"),
                    new JsonAttribute("message", "${message}"),
                }
        };
…

logger.Info(new
        {
            Name = "SomeName",
            Level = "SomeLevel",
            Message = "HelloWorld"
        });
```

Comment: yes this is exactly what I'm currently doing still not posting to cosmos

Comment: Have you also tried testing locally using the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator?

Comment: No I have not, I'll give it a try

Comment: when I was setting up the emulator I realized that I switched the collection name and the database name. now it's working